# Should accepted answers really show up as red?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Red on StackOverflow.com indicates down votes. Using red to highlight accepted answers really threw me off at first. Shouldn't the accepted highlight be green?

[image]

Comment: Where'd you see red? They're all green in my browsers.

Comment: Accepted answers are white type on a red background when I view my reputation. I'll attach a screenshot. Using Chrome

Comment: an excellent question. That is counterintuitive.

Comment: Oh, *those* markers. Yes, that's a good point.

Comment: This looks like a bug, it should be green, unless you got a bounty. bounty is red. We're looking into it.

Comment: Related:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is now fixed.

Check out the [new Beta theme](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/new-beta-theme-launched) that Jin deployed!